# Am trying to add up the total Minute an employee work for a month and get the summary at the end of the month

Tags: c#, .net

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<LatenessReportDetails>> GetLatenessReportDetails(DateTime periodFrom, DateTime periodTo, ApiToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            return await _DBContext.PayrollHrpayrollAttDetail.Where(x => x.CompanyId == token.CompanyId &&
                                    x.DivisionId == token.DivisionId &&
                                    x.DepartmentId == token.DepartmentId)
                                    .Where(x => x.TimeIn.Value > x.ExpectedTimeIn)
                                    .Select(x => new LatenessReportDetails
                                    {
                                        Date = x.SystemDate.Value,
                                        EmployeeId = x.EmployeeId,
                                        Name = x.EmployeeName,
                                        FirstName = x.EmployeeFirstName,
                                                    //LastName = x.EmployeeLastName,
                                        TimeInMinutes = (DateTime.Parse(x.TimeIn.Value.ToString()) -
                                        DateTime.Parse(x.ExpectedTimeIn.Value.ToString())).TotalMinutes
                                    }).ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: If i understand your use case, GroupBy is the ideal scenario.
......
.GroupBy(x => new { x.CompanyId, x.DivisionId ..})
.Select(x => new LatenessReportDetails
                                    {
                                        Name = x.First().EmployeeName,
                                        FirstName = x.First().EmployeeFirstName,
                                        TimeInMinutes = (x.Sum(DateTime.Parse(x.TimeIn.Value.ToString())) - x.Sum(DateTime.Parse(x.ExpectedTimeIn.Value.ToString()))).TotalMinutes
                                    }).ToListAsync();